# VSTS Copying cer file from azure keyvault into drop folder

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-keyvault

Am trying to create a release for a new project that expects a .cer file in its bin folder. The certificate is uploaded into Azure keyvault.

Is there  a way in VSTS Release steps to download this file and drop into the bin folder of the build artifact.

The closest i could achieve using powershell is

```
    $bytes = (Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "**" -Name "cplocal").Certificate.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert, $null)
    [io.file]::WriteAllBytes('c:\test.cer',$bytes)
```

But not sure how to write into drop folder.

Comment: I guess you can add an azure powershell task to download it from key vault ???

Comment: I have the powershell task to download from keyvault, but am not sure how to write into the drop folder.